# Save GridView state when clicking on edit button and returning back

Tags: php, yii2

First of all, let me explain the scenario:

I have a `GridView` in template and it works fine. Now imagine that a user did the following actions:

1. He applied some filters on data
2. He also sorted by some columns

What I want to do - is to save value of his actions, i.e save values of sorting columns and values of filters when he clicks on "edit -> save" and returns back.

It's something similar to flash, but for attributes. Is this even possible to do with Yii2's built-in tools?

Comment: Not sure this is possible by default, haven't found anything like that so far. I'm tracking that sort of thing in the session myself.

Comment: @BlueZed How do you do that anyway?

Comment: Well, after assigning the parameters to your search model and before you return the data provider you could simply store the search model in the session and then load it again when the user returns to the grid view. In one application I even use this method to store the filters in the user settings rather than the session so they persist between sessions, ie. after user logs out and back in again. Does that help?

Comment: @BlueZed Yes I got it. If you post it as an answer, I'd accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after assigning the parameters to your search model and before you return the data provider you could simply store the search model in the session and then load it again when the user returns to the grid view.

In one application I even use this method to store the filters in the user settings rather than the session so they persist between sessions, ie. after user logs out and back in again.